# understand functions that operate on whole array in groupby aggregation

Tags: arrays, numpy, pandas, group-by, aggregate

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'clients': pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']),
    'odd1': pd.Series([1, 1, 2, 1, 2]),
    'odd2': pd.Series([6, 7, 8, 9, 10])})

grpd = df.groupby(['clients', 'odd1']).agg({
    'odd2': lambda x: x/float(x.sum())
})
print grpd
```

The desired result is:

```
A   1   0.619047619
    2   0.380952381
B   1   0.473684211
    2   0.526316
```

I have browsed [around](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) but I still don't understand how having `lambda`s that operate on the whole array, f.ex. `x.sum()` work. Furthermore, I still miss the point on what `x` is in `x.sum()` wrt to the grouped columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> df.groupby(['clients', 'odd1'])['odd2'].sum() / df.groupby('clients')['odd2'].sum()
clients  odd1
A        1       0.619
         2       0.381
B        1       0.474
         2       0.526
Name: odd2, dtype: float64
```

or alternatively, use [`.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) to obtain values based on `clients` grouping and then sum for each `clients` and `odd1` grouping:

```
>>> df['val'] = df['odd2'] / df.groupby('clients')['odd2'].transform('sum')
>>> df
  clients  odd1  odd2    val
0       A     1     6  0.286
1       A     1     7  0.333
2       A     2     8  0.381
3       B     1     9  0.474
4       B     2    10  0.526
>>> df.groupby(['clients', 'odd1'])['val'].sum()
clients  odd1
A        1       0.619
         2       0.381
B        1       0.474
         2       0.526
Name: val, dtype: float64
```